# Exercise in accumulation points of sum and product bounded complex sets

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Our professor give us the following question:
Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{C}$ be two complex bounded sets such that $\mbox{acc}(A)\subset\{0\}$ and $\mbox{acc}(B)\subset\{0\}.$ The  question is true that $\mbox{acc}\,(AB)\subset \{0\}$ and $\mbox{acc}\,(A+B)\subset \{0\}?;$ where $AB:=\{ab \text{ such that } a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\},$ $A+B:=\{a+b \text{ such that } a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}$ and $\mbox{acc}(A)$ means the accumulation points of $A$ ?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I try something  but is so far to the solution

Answer (score 1):

**First problem**: $\text{acc}(AB)={0}$.

Proof:

There is an upper bound on $|z|$ for $z\in A\cup B$. Call that upper bound $M$.

For any $r>0$, the closed ring $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:r\leq|z|\leq M\}$ is compact.

It follows that there are only finitely many elements $a\in A$ such that $|a|\geq r$. (Why?)

Likewise for $B$.

If $a\in A$ has modulus less than $r$, or $b\in B$ has modulus less than $r$, or both, then $|ab|<Mr$.

The only way to get $|ab|\geq Mr$ is when both $|a|\geq r$ and $|b|\geq r$. Since there is only a finite number of each, the number of possible products of such pairs is also finite.

It follows that for all $r>0$, there are only finitely many elements $z\in AB$ such that $|z|\geq Mr$.

But $AB$ is not a finite set, so the only accumulation point of $AB$ is $0$.

$\\$

**Second problem**: $\text{acc}(A+B)\neq{0}$.

Indeed, there exists $a\in A$ with $a\neq0$.

Now $\{a\}+B$ has the single accumulation point $a$.

Comment: First, thank you very much for the answer. For your question, i think because the ring $C_{r,M}:=\{z: r \leq |z| \leq M \}$ is compact and the well known Bolzano-Wiestrass theorem and the fact that $\mbox{acc}\,(A)\subset\{0\}$ imply that $A\cap C_{r,M}$ is finite.

Comment: Why there are only finitely many elements $z\in AB$ such that $|z|≥Mr$ ?

Comment: If either $a\in A$ or $b\in B$ has modulus less than $r$, then $|ab|<Mr$

Comment: I dont inderstand how this implies that there a finitely many elemens $z \in AB$ such that $|z|\geq Mr$

Comment: Can you explain to way ?

Comment: The only way that $|ab|\geq Mr$ is when both $a$ and $b$ have modulus greater than $r$

Comment: Until this moment your answer is not clear mr or i have a probleme to understand the proof. Add some explication please

Comment: I dont understand  your language, can you write the answer in english

Comment: OK, I've edited the explanation to make it clearer. I'm going to have to stop here.